# Where do I find the host IP address for an app deployed in minikube

Tags: minikube, ifconfig

I'm deploying a spring boot app in minikube that connects to a database running on the host.  Where do I find the IP address that the app can use to get back to the host?  For docker I can use `ifconfig` and get the IP address from the `docker0` entry.  `ifconfig` shows another device with IP address `172.18.0.1`.  Would that be how my app would get back to the host?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was the `172.18.0.1` IP address.  I passed it to the Spring app running in minikube with a configmap like this:

`kubectl create configmap springdatasourceurl --from-literal=SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://172.18.0.1:5432/bookservice`

The app also needed `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME` to be set in a configmap and that credentials `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD` and `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME` be set as secrets.

More information on configmap and secret are [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-configmaps-and-secrets-68d061f7ab5b).

Comment: Does not answer the question. How can someone find the host IP?

Answer (score 5):

I think I understood you correctly and this is what you are asking for.

Minikube is started as a VM on your machine. You need to know the IP which Minikube starts with. This can be done with `minikube status` or `minikube ip`, output might look like:

```
$ minikube status
minikube: Running
cluster: Running
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.1
```

This will only provide you the IP address of Minikube not your application.
In order to connect to your app from outside the Minikube you need to expose it as a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

Example of a `Service` might look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1  
kind: Service  
metadata:  
  name: webapp  
spec:  
  type: NodePort  
  ports:  
    - nodePort: 31317  
      port: 8080  
      protocol: TCP  
      targetPort: 8080  
  selector:  
    app: webapp
```

You can see results:

```
$ kubectl get services -o wide  
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE       SELECTOR  
postgres   ClusterIP   10.0.0.140   <none>        5432/TCP         32m       app=postgres  
webapp     NodePort    10.0.0.235   <none>        8080:31317/TCP   2s        app=webapp
```

You will be able to connect to the webapp from inside the Cluster using `10.0.0.235:8080` of from outside the Cluster using `Minikube IP` and port `31317`.

I also recommend going through [Hello Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/) tutorial.